# Long start time on App startup

Tags: android, performance

I have an Android app that normally starts very quickly.  If the phone is somewhere where cell/internet coverage is on the edge, it sits at a white screen on startup, sometimes up to 30 seconds.  If have put in debug Toast messages, and it appears that the pause is before any code of mine is started.  Are there libraries or something that will attempt internet traffic on startup?

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'    
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The app uses push notifications which is the only thing I can think of that might be causing the issue.

Comment: probably is firebase doing that, a good solution is to make a splash screen.
Try clean unused things in code

Comment: Unless you have a custom `Application` class in your manifest, or unless one of those libraries adds some poorly-written `ContentProvider`, nothing should interfere with the launching of your activity. The first thing that you should do is get rid of `play-services` and add in the *specific pieces* of the Play Services SDK that you need. See "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable" in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). Once you have gotten rid of that cruft, if the problem persists, use method tracing to see where you are spending your time.